# @JsonIgnore with Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I'm having difficulty getting @JsonIgnore to work with Cloud Endpoints.

If I add @JsonIgnore to my getter from com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore the property is successfully suppressed. (But then I get the nasty 'Warning Error' that my app might break)

However, when I switch @JsonIgnore to org.codehaus.jackson.annotate from jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar, Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library ignores my @JsonIgnore annotation and creates the model class with the property I am trying to suppress.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use @JsonIgnore, use [`@ApiResourceProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apiresourceproperty) instead:

> @ApiResourceProperty provides provides more control over how resource
>   properties are exposed in the API. You can use it on a property getter
>   or setter to omit the property from an API resource. You can also use
>   it on the field itself, if the field is private, to expose it in the
>   API. You can also use this annotation to change the name of a property
>   in an API resource.

```
@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
public String getBin() {
  return bin;
}
```

Comment: What about dealing with legacy classes, from 3rd party libraries. I need to exclude some getters that fail to serialize and don't even need to

Comment: I thought about overriding that getter and add your annotation, but I can't as it's marked as final. Surely there should be a simple way to tell Jackson to skip some or all public getters (mixins?)